# electron-vue: 'module is not defined'

Tags: webpack, vue.js, electron

I use electron-vue to create an app,when run `npm run dev`,it is good, but when run `npm run pack`,when open the index.html,I got the error in console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
>       at renderer.js:1

Anyone knows why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is expected when you transpile with webpack using the option `libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'` in the output of webpack as explain here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget

Answer (score 0):

The electron-vue is not being updated at this time. (currently, electronic version 2.x)

There's a boilerplate that I forked the electron-vue and updated all the modules with the latest modules. The use method is the same and we have added the ui framework and css-precessor.

- Electron 5
- Vue-CLI 3
- Babel 7
- Vue 2.6
- css-preprocessor

  - Sass
  - Less
  - Stylus
- UI Framework

  - Quasar 1.x
  - Vuteify 2.x

We recommend you try it.

https://github.com/kdydesign/vue-electron5